# visual studio express 2013 launcher wont start

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am trying to install VS Express 2013 for web, when I am launching vns_full.exe I can see the visual studio logo for 1 sec and it is disappear. No errors just nothing happens. I cant find process in  task manager, I don't see anything in event viewer.
I have been able to install VS 2010 with no problem. I did check the dependency that is required to run VS Express for web. I have IE 11 , MS C++ 2013 Redistributable, Windows 7 SP1 x64

I tried install reinstall different frameworks 4., 4.5.1 etc
I am not really sure what can fix my problem any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Use the [`/l logfilename` switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h7fzkw.aspx) and see what's in the log

Comment: if I understand correct the log file supposed to be in 
Users\User Name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Ver\logfile
but I dont see anything, could be it stored some where in temp?
any suggestions where to look for logfile?

Comment: @user243772 the point of the /l switch is that you can specify where you want the log file to be created